# Display property of object in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

So I have to display a list of product types in a asp.net web-form's listview

So far I have been able to populate the listview and display the type of object with container.DataItem but I can't find how to display, lets say, the name of the product type.

the code behind is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IList<ProductType> productTypes = getProductTypes();
            ListView1.DataSource = productTypes;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

And the .aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table width="200px">
                <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="<% WHRE THE NAME SHOULD BE DISPLAYED %>" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

So far I've seen that in some cases they use "Eval()" and the name of the property but in those the object is defined in the code behind which is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use foreach? ListView is quite rigid. You have more power over your code this way, with really no more work to do:

Codebehind:

```
public List<ProductType> productTypes;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    productTypes = getProductTypes();
}
```

And page code:

```
<table>
    <% foreach(var p in productTypes) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><% = p.Id %></td><td><% = p.Name %></td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: Just don't forget to expose model(s) with public modifier (first line in the code) or it will be inaccessible to page front end. MVC works this way, you should move into it.